# Pass table input to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to programming and I want to pass a table input value to the controller. I tried this:

```
$("#btnsend").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json ; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            buyerID: $('.BuyerID').val(),
        },
        url: "/SaveReservation",
        success: function (data) {
        alert('buyerID : ' + data);
        },
        error: function (result) {

            alert('something went wrong');
        }
    })
});
```

The controller is like this :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult SaveReservation(BuyerModel buyer)
{
    return Json(buyer.DistibutorID);
}
```

When I click the button I get a success state but in the alert I get all the source code of the project after the word `buyerID`.

Comment: do you want to pass the whole Model or just one value of BuyerID? you are using a class selector. Is it because there are multiple buyerIds that you want to submit to the controller? What is in the BuyerModel class?

Comment: Instead of putting that in an alert.. use `console.log(data)` and then in the console tell what the value of `data` is

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
return Json(new { success = true, message = buyer.DistibutorID }, 
                 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And:

```
alert('buyerID : ' + data.message );
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this here in your script

```
data: {
buyerID: $('.BuyerID').val(),
},
```

Either must have the same structure as your BuyerModel Here

```
public JsonResult SaveReservation(BuyerModel buyer) <- BuyerModel that you are using
{
    return Json(buyer.DistibutorID);
}
```

Or you can Just Change your Controller to accept only one argument Like this

```
public JsonResult SaveReservation(string buyerID) <- Follow the same Object structure you are passing in Ajax
{
    return Json(buyer.DistibutorID);
}
```